# undefined symbol error when loading a module, using AWS C++ SDK, in Freeswitch

Tags: c++, freeswitch, amazon-polly, aws-sdk-cpp

I am asking this question again as the mods decided to close my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297465/undefined-symbol-znk3aws35amazonserializablewebservicerequest7getbodyev-tr) as a duplicate, within minutes of it being asked (and also down-voted!!). Now I have gone through all [33 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) of what was thought to be an answer to my solution, but it didn't help. So I am asking again.

> I am trying to build a FreeSWITCH module to add text-to-speech functionality using AWS Polly & the AWS C++ SDK.
> Dev environment is Debian 8, g++ 4.9.2. AWS C++ SDK is built using instructions here except that I turned off shared libs (produces .a lib files).

The AWS C++ SDK was built as recommended [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/wiki/Building-the-SDK-from-source-on-EC2) (basically C++ code with C++ linkage). `mod_polly.cpp` is built with C++ linkage as well to produce `mod_polly.so`. It does refer to some C headers & functions. This was built as -

> g++ -shared -o mod_polly.so -L/usr/local/lib/ -laws-cpp-sdk-polly -laws-cpp-sdk-core -fPIC -g -ggdb -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -I/usr/src/freeswitch/src/include/ -I/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/libteletone/src/ mod_polly.cpp

Source below -

```
extern "C" {
#include <switch.h>
}


#include <fstream>

#define BIG_ENDIAN_SYSTEM (*(uint16_t *)"\0\xff" < 0x100)

#define REVERSE_BYTES(...) do for(size_t REVERSE_BYTES=0; REVERSE_BYTES<sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)>>1; ++REVERSE_BYTES)\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES],\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES],\
    ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[REVERSE_BYTES] ^= ((unsigned char*)&(__VA_ARGS__))[sizeof(__VA_ARGS__)-1-REVERSE_BYTES];\
while(0)

#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentials.h>
#include <aws/core/client/ClientConfiguration.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/Outcome.h>
#include <aws/polly/PollyClient.h>
#include <aws/polly/model/SynthesizeSpeechRequest.h>
#include <aws/polly/model/SynthesizeSpeechResult.h>
#include <aws/polly/model/TextType.h>
#include <aws/polly/model/LanguageCode.h>
#include <aws/polly/model/OutputFormat.h>
#include <aws/polly/model/VoiceId.h>

typedef unsigned long DWORD;    // 32-bit unsigned integer
typedef unsigned short WORD;    // 16-bit unsigned integer

struct riff                                 // Data             Bytes   Total
{
    char            chunkID[4];             // "RIFF"           4       4
    DWORD           riffSize;               // file size - 8    4       8
    char            typeID[4];              // "WAVE"           4       12
    char            formatChunkID[4];       // "fmt "           4       16
    DWORD           formatChunkSize;        // 16 bytes         4       20          
    WORD            formatTag;              //                  2       22
    WORD            noOfChannels;           //                  2       24
    DWORD           samplesPerSec;          //                  4       28
    DWORD           bytesPerSec;            //                  4       32
    WORD            blockAlign;             //                  2       34
    WORD            bitsPerSample;          //                  2       36
    char            dataChunkID[4];         // "data"           4       40
    DWORD           dataChunkSize;          // not fixed        4       44
};

static struct {
    switch_mutex_t *mutex;
    switch_thread_rwlock_t *running_rwlock;
    switch_memory_pool_t *pool;
    int running;
} process;

static struct {
    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials *credentials;
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration *config;
    Aws::SDKOptions *options;
} globals;

switch_loadable_module_interface_t *MODULE_INTERFACE;

static char *supported_formats[SWITCH_MAX_CODECS] = { 0 };

/* Prototypes */

SWITCH_MODULE_LOAD_FUNCTION(mod_polly_load);
SWITCH_MODULE_SHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(mod_polly_shutdown);
SWITCH_MODULE_DEFINITION(mod_polly, mod_polly_load, mod_polly_shutdown, NULL);

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Implementation */

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const riff& h)
{
    if BIG_ENDIAN_SYSTEM {
        struct riff hdr = std::move(h);

        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.riffSize);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.formatChunkSize);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.formatTag);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.noOfChannels);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.samplesPerSec);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.bytesPerSec);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.blockAlign);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.bitsPerSample);
        REVERSE_BYTES(hdr.dataChunkSize);

        return out 
            .write(hdr.chunkID, 4)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.riffSize, 4)
            .write(hdr.typeID, 4)
            .write(hdr.formatChunkID, 4)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.formatChunkSize, 4)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.formatTag, 2)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.noOfChannels, 2)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.samplesPerSec, 4)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.bytesPerSec, 4)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.blockAlign, 2)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.bitsPerSample, 2)
            .write(hdr.dataChunkID, 4)
            .write((const char *)&hdr.dataChunkSize, 4);
    } else {
        return out
            .write(h.chunkID, 4)
            .write((const char *)&h.riffSize, 4)
            .write(h.typeID, 4)
            .write(h.formatChunkID, 4)
            .write((const char *)&h.formatChunkSize, 4)
            .write((const char *)&h.formatTag, 2)
            .write((const char *)&h.noOfChannels, 2)
            .write((const char *)&h.samplesPerSec, 4)
            .write((const char *)&h.bytesPerSec, 4)
            .write((const char *)&h.blockAlign, 2)
            .write((const char *)&h.bitsPerSample, 2)
            .write(h.dataChunkID, 4)
            .write((const char *)&h.dataChunkSize, 4);
    }
}

riff init_pcm_header(std::ostream& in)
{
    // get length of file
    in.seekp(0, in.end);
    DWORD sz = in.tellp();
    in.seekp(0, in.beg);

    struct riff result = {
        {'R','I','F','F'},      // chunkID
        sz + 0x24,              // riffSize         (size of stream + 0x24) or (file size - 8)
        {'W','A','V','E'},      // typeID
        {'f','m','t',' '},      // formatChunkID
        16,                     // formatChunkSize
        1,                      // formatTag        (PCM)
        1,                      // noOfChannels     (mono)
        8000,                   // samplesPerSec    (8KHz)
        16000,                  // bytesPerSec      ((Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8)
        2,                      // blockAlign       ((bits per sample * channels) / 8)
        16,                     // bitsPerSample    (multiples of 8)
        {'d','a','t','a'},      // dataChunkID
        sz                      // dataChunkSize    (sample size)   
    };

    return result;
}

struct voice_sync {
    char* session_uuid;
    Aws::IOStream *audio_stream;
    switch_size_t blockAlign;
};

typedef struct voice_sync voice_sync_t;

static switch_status_t polly_file_open(switch_file_handle_t *handle, const char *path)
{
    voice_sync_t *sync_info = (voice_sync_t*)malloc(sizeof(voice_sync_t));
    sync_info->audio_stream = new Aws::StringStream(std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    handle->private_info = sync_info;
    handle->samplerate = 8000;
    handle->channels = 1;
    handle->pos = 0;
    handle->format = 0;
    handle->sections = 0;
    handle->seekable = 0;
    handle->speed = 0.5;

    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "submitting text [%s] to polly", path);

    Aws::Polly::PollyClient polly_client(*globals.credentials, *globals.config);
    Aws::Polly::Model::SynthesizeSpeechRequest request;

    request.SetLanguageCode(Aws::Polly::Model::LanguageCode::en_US);
    request.SetOutputFormat(Aws::Polly::Model::OutputFormat::pcm);
    request.SetSampleRate("8000");
    request.SetTextType(Aws::Polly::Model::TextType::text);  // or ssml
    request.SetVoiceId(Aws::Polly::Model::VoiceId::Matthew);
    request.SetText(path);

    if (handle->params) {
        // get the session UUID for this channel
        // note: this doesnt fire for a standard call session in the audio context; is there a way to make sure it is there?
        const char *uuid = switch_event_get_header(handle->params, "session");
        if (!zstr(uuid)) {
            sync_info->session_uuid = switch_core_strdup(handle->memory_pool, uuid);
            switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_UUID_LOG(sync_info->session_uuid), SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Polly linked to session %s\n", sync_info->session_uuid);
        }
    }
    sync_info->audio_stream->clear();
//    sync_info->audio_stream.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    auto outcome = polly_client.SynthesizeSpeech(request);

    // Output operation status
    if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "received audio response for %s", request.GetServiceRequestName());

        Aws::Polly::Model::SynthesizeSpeechResult& result = ((Aws::Polly::Model::SynthesizeSpeechResult&)(outcome));
        Aws::IOStream*  audio_stream = &result.GetAudioStream();

        // this is raw PCM so we need to add a wav header!
        riff header = init_pcm_header(*audio_stream);
        *sync_info->audio_stream << header;

        // tansfer audio data into stream
        *sync_info->audio_stream << audio_stream->rdbuf();
        sync_info->audio_stream->seekp(0, sync_info->audio_stream->beg);

        // update handle information about audio stream
        handle->samplerate = header.samplesPerSec;
        handle->channels = header.noOfChannels;
        handle->format = header.formatTag;
        handle->duration = header.dataChunkSize / header.bytesPerSec +1;
        handle->samples_in = header.dataChunkSize / header.blockAlign +1;

        sync_info->blockAlign = header.blockAlign;

        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "polly audio stream ready; duration: %ld secs", handle->duration);
        return SWITCH_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_ERROR, "something went wrong retrieving audio from polly");
    return SWITCH_STATUS_FALSE;
}

static switch_status_t polly_file_close(switch_file_handle_t *handle)
{
    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "closiing polly audio stream");

    voice_sync_t *sync_info = (voice_sync_t*)handle->private_info;

    //sync_info->audio_stream->close(); -- doesnt exist on stringstream
    delete sync_info->audio_stream;

    if (sync_info->session_uuid) {
        switch_safe_free(sync_info->session_uuid);
    }

    switch_safe_free(sync_info);
    handle->private_info = NULL;

    return SWITCH_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

static switch_status_t polly_file_read(switch_file_handle_t *handle, void *data, size_t *len)
{
    voice_sync_t *sync_info = (voice_sync_t*)handle->private_info;
    switch_size_t bytes;

    sync_info->audio_stream->read((char *)data, *len * sync_info->blockAlign);
    if ((bytes = sync_info->audio_stream->gcount()) <= 0) {
        return SWITCH_STATUS_FALSE;
    }

    *len = bytes / sync_info->blockAlign;
    return SWITCH_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

SWITCH_MODULE_LOAD_FUNCTION(mod_polly_load)
{
    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Initializing polly audio interface");

    supported_formats[0] = (char*)"polly";

    /*
        switch_application_interface_t *app_interface;
        switch_api_interface_t *api_interface;
    */
    switch_file_interface_t *file_interface;

    *module_interface = switch_loadable_module_create_module_interface(pool, modname);
    file_interface = (switch_file_interface_t*)switch_loadable_module_create_interface(*module_interface, SWITCH_FILE_INTERFACE);
    file_interface->interface_name = modname;
    file_interface->extens = supported_formats;
    file_interface->file_open = polly_file_open;
    file_interface->file_close = polly_file_close;
    file_interface->file_read = polly_file_read;

    MODULE_INTERFACE = *module_interface;

    memset(&process, 0, sizeof(process));
    memset(&globals, 0, sizeof(globals));
    process.pool = pool;

    switch_thread_rwlock_create(&process.running_rwlock, pool);
    switch_mutex_init(&process.mutex, SWITCH_MUTEX_NESTED, pool);

    globals.options = new Aws::SDKOptions();
    globals.options->loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Debug;

    globals.credentials = new Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials();
    globals.credentials->SetAWSAccessKeyId("your aws key");
    globals.credentials->SetAWSSecretKey("your aws secret");

    globals.config = new Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration();
    globals.config->region = "eu-west-1";  // Ireland

    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Initializing aws api");

    Aws::InitAPI(*globals.options);

    switch_thread_rwlock_wrlock(process.running_rwlock);
    process.running = 1;
    switch_thread_rwlock_unlock(process.running_rwlock);

    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Ready to rock!");

    /* indicate that the module should continue to be loaded */
    return SWITCH_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

SWITCH_MODULE_SHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(mod_polly_shutdown)
{   
    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Shutting down polly polly audio interface");

    switch_thread_rwlock_wrlock(process.running_rwlock);
    process.running = 0;
    switch_thread_rwlock_unlock(process.running_rwlock);

    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Closing aws api");
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(*globals.options);

    delete globals.credentials;
    delete globals.config;
    delete globals.options;

    switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_DEBUG, "Module shutdown finished");
    return SWITCH_STATUS_UNLOAD;
}
```

Now when i try to load this on `Freeswitch` , it throws an error

> 2019-07-31 22:00:51.918181 [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1522 Error Loading module /usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_polly.so
>
> /usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_polly.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK3Aws35AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest7GetBodyEv

Freeswitch is C code with C++ guards in header files (extern "C" declaration).

Looking at symbols in `mod_polly.so`

> readelf -Ws mod_polly.so | grep _ZNK3Aws35AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest7GetBodyEv
>
> 66: 0000000000000000 0 NOTYPE GLOBAL DEFAULT UND _ZNK3Aws35AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest7GetBodyEv
>
> 590: 0000000000000000 0 NOTYPE GLOBAL DEFAULT UND _ZNK3Aws35AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest7GetBodyEv

Now my basic understanding of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/26233563#26233563) tells me that the symbol is present in the `so` file but `Freeswitch` cannot find it or load it.

Now this error has very likely to do with mixing C/C++ code but looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574420#12574420) and [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mixingcandcpluspluscode-305840.html) hasn't helped me figure out how to fix it.

I do not want to build `Freeswitch` to load my module and I am thinking I shouldn't have to, as that renders this project un-scalable.

What am I missing here?

PS:

> readelf -Ws libaws-cpp-sdk-core.a | grep AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest7GetBodyEv
>
> 165: 0000000000000000   716 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   42 _ZNK3Aws35AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest7GetBodyEv

Symbol is defined in `libaws-cpp-sdk-core.a` which is part of the compilation command for `mod_polly.cpp`

Comment: No, the symbol is not present in the `.so`, what you see is the reference itself. You have to figure out which other shared library defines this symbol, and make sure you link with it.

Comment: it's in `libaws-cpp-sdk-core.a` which is included in build command. added info in question

Comment: You'll just have to figure this out, because only you would know things like whether or not they might be duplicate libraries installed, or a shared library version of the same static library, resulting in a confused link. You say "Symbol is defined in libaws-cpp-sdk-core.a", but is it the libaws-cpp-sdk-core.a where `-L/usr/local/lib` instructs the linker to search. Little details like that matter, and only you have all the details of how things work on your system.

Comment: Yes, `/usr/local/lib` is where the library is. I know I have to do it but your 1st comment was helpful. At least I now know that I was reading `readelf` output incorrectly, so maybe it's just ordering of lib files while building.

Comment: Does the process of building this `.a` file include running `ranlib`? If not, then that's what's missing.

Comment: new to linux build env, so i don't even know what `ranlib` does. But problem solved for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Sam V - turns out it was ordering issue while building. Change in ordering of build command to

> g++ -shared -o mod_polly.so -fPIC -g -ggdb -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -I/usr/src/freeswitch/src/include/ -I/usr/src/freeswitch/libs/libteletone/src/ mod_polly.cpp -L/usr/local/lib/ -laws-cpp-sdk-polly -laws-cpp-sdk-core

fixed the problem. Your 1st comment was the key. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to build a working mod_polly module?  I tried with the AWS C++ SDK and kept hitting memory corruption errors.  Having to carefully turn C++ objects into C objects, and back, was painful, and probably error prone.